# Как в laravel маскировать данные input

Tags: ajax, json, laravel

братья прогеры, столкнулся с такой проблемой, данные которые приходят с JSON, допустим пришел ответ JSON в поле дата рождения 05.06.1995 выдал такие данные, а надо чтобы они прилетали в поле input примерно в таком виде $$.06.19$$, только вместо доллара должны быть звездочки, никогда не сталкивался с таким, благодарю за помощь

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: маскировка здесь очевидная: вырезать куски строк, заменить на другие. первый вопрос, где это делать? если это не сильно важная информация и маскировка нужна, к примеру, от чужого взгляда через плечо пользователя, то сделать это можно прямо на странице средствами javascript. если это очень важная информация, типа номера карты, которую нельзя светить, то это обязательно надо делать на сервере, то есть на php. в зависимости от языка соответствующее решение

Comment: @bars на фреймворке laravel, да информация важная, поэтому нужно на стороне бэкенда)

Answer (score 0):

ну для вашего вопроса используются мутаторы. Прочитайте в документации про них. Далее приведу пример как правильно делать.

**Во-первых**. Необходимо спрятать в выборке данное значение поля бд. Например оно называется `birthdate`, значит в модели указываете:

```
class User extends Model
{
    ...
    protected $hidden = ['birthdate'];
    ...
}
```

В результате в выборке фронт не увидит данное значение, но на бэке для обработки можно так же использовать его `$user->birthdate`.

**Во-вторых**. Теперь необходимо вернуть на фронт зашифрованное значение в замен исходного спрятанного. Для это создадим мутатор:

```
class User extends Model
{
    ...
    protected $hidden = ['birthdate'];
    protected $appends= ['encode_birthdate'];
    ...

    public function getEncodeBirthdateAttribute()
    {
        $time = strtotime($this->birthdate);
        return '**.'.date('m', $time).'.'.substr(date('Y', $time), 0, 2).'**';
    }
}
```

В результате на фронте появится значение `encode_birthdate` в объекте модели полученной.